# Kotlin map function combined with put to map

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, map-function

Im trying to do following in simplest way.
I'd need to map list of objects into hashMap so that value1 is the key and value2 is entry object.

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Account>()
accountInfo.map {
    map.put( it.value1 to it.value2 )
}
```

or

```
val map2 = accountInfo.map {
    it.value1 to it.value2
}
```

but both are somehow wrong

first one says it only wants string as input.
Second one tells me its going to return `List<Pair<String, Account>>`

Why ?! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**use** `put(x, y)`

Not `put( x to y)`